# FirebaseRecyclerAdapter when scrolling,images begin to appear in all viewHolder uncontolled

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

In chat app,i have a message items,each message can contain a text field,or text and image...i list items with FirebaseRecyclerAdapter,and everythings ok,message containing only text show only text,and message with image show text and image...but,when i scrolling up or down,at once,images begin to appear uncontrolled in other messages,messages that do not contain images,at once all messages showing images,how it is possible,anybody know why is this happening?

heres my firebaseadapter:

```
mFirebaseAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ForumMessage,MessageViewHolder>(
            ForumMessage.class,
            R.layout.podforum_item,
            MessageViewHolder.class,
            storeOffers) {

        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(final MessageViewHolder viewHolder,
                                          ForumMessage friendlyMessage, int position) {


            viewHolder.messageTextView.setText(friendlyMessage.getBody());
            viewHolder.messageTextView.setVisibility(TextView.VISIBLE);
            //viewHolder.messageImageView.setVisibility(ImageView.GONE);

            if (friendlyMessage.getDodataSlika() != null){
                Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
                        .load(friendlyMessage.getDodataSlika())
                        .into(viewHolder.messageImageView);
                viewHolder.messageImageView.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
                // viewHolder.messageTextView.setVisibility(TextView.GONE);
            }




            viewHolder.messengerTextView.setText(friendlyMessage.getAuthor());
            if (friendlyMessage.getSlika() == null) {
                viewHolder.messengerImageView.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(TemaActivity.this,
                        R.drawable.ic_account_circle_black_36dp));
            } else {
                Glide.with(TemaActivity.this)
                        .load(friendlyMessage.getSlika())
                        .into(viewHolder.messengerImageView);
            }
            //recipient_sender.add(friendlyMessage.getRecipient_sender());
            // recipient.add(friendlyMessage.getRecipient());
            // sender.add(friendlyMessage.getSender());


        }


    };
    temaRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLinearLayoutManager);
    temaRecyclerView.setAdapter(mFirebaseAdapter);
```

Comment: maybe it is because of recycler view as it recycle the views. Try using firebaselistadapter

Answer (score 0):

Even I was having the same sort of issue. To tackle it , I created a native recyclerview .

Your code would look something like this:-

```
public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.ViewHolder> {

     //your object resource
     ArrayList<Object> resource;
     int itemResource;
     Context mContext;


public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    Object currentGEvent;
    ViewHolder holder;

    //your views here

    final TextView title;
    final TextView details;
    final ImageView gEventPicture;        
    final Context mContext;
    final ImageView profilePicture;

    View itemView;


    public ViewHolder(Context context, View itemView) {
        super(itemView);


        this.mContext = context;

        title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.geventTitle);
        details = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.gEventsDetails);
        gEventPicture = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.photoOf);
        profilePicture = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.exampleProfilePic);


        this.itemView = itemView;
    }

    public void bindGEvent(final Object gEvent, ViewHolder viewHolder) {

       //Here you set text and the imageviews
    }

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return this.resource.size();
}

public CustomAdapter(Context context, int itemResource, ArrayList<Object> gEvents) {

    this.itemResource = itemResource;
    this.mContext = context;
    this.resource = gEvents;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(this.itemResource, parent, false);


    //view.setLayoutParams(new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    return new ViewHolder(this.mContext, view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    Object gEvent = this.resource.get(position);
    holder.bindGEvent(gEvent, holder);

}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return super.getItemViewType(position);
}
```

}